# How to place a login form in the center of a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to create the following layout:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                           |
|                                                           |
|                                                           |
|                                                           |
|                 L-Email     [___________]-R               |
|                 L-Password  [___________]-R               |
|                                   (Login)-R               |
|                                                           |
|                                                           |
|                                                           |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
```

So what I'm trying is that I created a linear layout, every e-mail, password and the login line is a linearlayout. But what i want is to place the whole thing into the center (vertically and horizontaly) and align the Email and password labels to the "L-" part of the screen ("L-" is just to indicate that i want to align to there) while i want to align the two text boxes and the login button to the "-R" sign (so I actually don't need the L- and -R signs, these are just indicates the align position here in this mockup)

Here is a more specific mockup:

[image: Example mockup]

So i want to align the whole thing to center and align the text labels to the left green line while the others to the right green line.

At this time i prefer to use  the Graphical Editor in eclipse but any suggestion is welcome.

I've tried this one so far but have become stuck:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sahbg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: Layout result]

Comment: Try using **RelativeLayout**. If for some reason you wish to use LinearLayout only use android:gravity and android:layout_gravity attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your existing code:

1. Change the height and width of the outer LinearLayout:

   ```
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ```

   (And you may need to change `gravity="center"` to `layout_gravity="center"`, honestly I can't remember which is which at this moment.)
2. Switch the "password" LinearLayout's width to `match_parent` so both the "username" and "password" rows are the same width.
3. Remove the LinearLayout that holds the Button, since it is not necessary, and add:

   ```
   android:layout_gravity="right"
   ```

   To the Button to shift it over to the right. You can also use this on the EditTexts and give them a specific width to force them to be the same size.

Comment: With your modifications it looks better now:
http://i.imgur.com/gHKunAQ.jpg
Now i need to take care about the textviews, i need to insert some space between the edittext and the textview. but with  this i also need to align the textviews to the left as seen on my image posted in my original question (align the textview to the left green line)

Comment: Use `layout_marginLeft="5dp"` in the EditText to add a small space between the TextView and EditText. The TextViews should be aligned to the left by default (if they aren't add `android:layout_gravity="left"`.)

Comment: Almost got it: http://i.imgur.com/3zen2ha.jpg and the code is: http://pastebin.com/7vr8fmTU why is that top linearlayout goes to the left a little bit? by the way if the textviews have the same text, the layout is ok, but i need different text ofcourse.

Comment: Ok, set the "username" and "password" LinearLayout widths to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. This way both layouts are the same size.

Comment: Thanks. I had to set only the username's linearlayout to match_parent and also set the top edittext to android:layout_marginLeft="62dp" <- i dont know why is this needed but this do the trick.

Comment: using the `android:layout_gravity="center"` is the elixir that worked for me.